# What parts of the codebase are making binaries large?

Tags: c, embedded, cross-compiling, microcontroller

I have built some code for a simulator and am now trying to use TI's free toolchain to cross-compile to a target with 64kb of nvram. The compiler claims that my code is about 34kb beyond the ROM:

```
(...) msp430-elf/bin/ld: region `ROM' overflowed by 33716 bytes
```

Another line says it cannot fit the `.text` field into its allotted space. I cannot believe that my additions are 34kb in total, let alone causing the binaries to overflow by this amount.

- The .o files my code has added to the project are a small fraction (200kb of the 1.9MB) of the project's total, and I have taken out a great deal of components that were in the project to begin with.
- I am already passing the compiler the `-Os -s` flags.
- The new code has about 100 characters worth of string literals.
- My code uses many `math.h` functions (in fact it is the only part that does floating point arithmetic), make a call to `strtod`, and make a call to `sprintf`

Are there any tools or methods to breaks down what is causing the binaries to be so large?

Comment: Take a look at the linker-generated map file, it should hopefully tell you everything you need.

Comment: I'd like to see your own answer on how did you actually solve this ;)

Comment: look for invisible (i.e. the compiler/linker put them there, not you) routines in the map file for unwanted 'pc' stuff like process exit handlers, exception handlers, divide-by-zero handlers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GNU binutils has tools to help you determine the size of each symbol or just each object file.

Have a look at `size` for instance: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/binutils/size.1.en.html

`nm` is also worth a try, as it can show the size of each symbol in the object code: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/binutils/nm.1.en.html

Carefully inspecting the output of `size` and `nm` will give you intuition for what takes up much space and what doesn't.

Know that `printf`, `sprintf` and many of the more complex library functions can often take up quite a few kB of extra ROM.

Floating point support using soft-floats will also bloat the code compared to using hard-float, i.e. using software emulation vs. hardware instructions to handle floating point.

Sometimes the compiler will add an astonishing amount of bloat :)

Answer (score 6):

I once also had memory issues with a tiny MSP430 controller.
The TI toolchain is linking large libraries into your binary if negative values are possible or floating point is used. In my case, it was about 10% - 20% of total memory usage.

TI's free Code composer Studio does provide a very powerful memory visualization (View -> Memory Allocation)

What helped me a lot was changing the Initialization Model in the Linker settings and other optimization options. I am currently not working with an MSP430 controller so I can not tell you details any more.

Answer (score 0):

There is also AMAP, a small and easy gui to view .map files: http://www.sikorskiy.net/prj/amap/

It would have been nice to have a kdirstat-like tool that lets you visually compare symbol sizes.

Although not a direct answer to the question, I ended up using Voidware's CORDIC implementation to avoid using the large functions in `<math.h>`: https://github.com/enthdegree/cordic_wrapped